# imbalanced data classification with boosting algorithms

Tags: classification

I am working on a binary data classification problem. The dataset is imbalanced, it consists of 92% 'false' labels and 8% 'true' labels. The number of features is 18 and I have a small number of 650 data points. I want to use boosting algorithms in matlab like 'GentleBoost' to solve this problem. I assign uniform for prior as follows:

ada = fitensemble(Xtrain,Ytrain,'GentleBoost',10,'Tree','LearnRate',0.1, 'prior', 'uniform');

but the performance is consistently poor. How should I set the parameters? Is it necessary to set a cost? How can I do this?Is there any classifier that perform better than this?

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I found that simpler approaches often work best. Instead of trying to  tweak your boosting parameters, have you first tried the following approaches (increasing in complexity):

1) change the objective function to use the average classification accuracy (or some weighted accuracy) of the two classes, with different classifiers, e.g., SVM, J4.5 etc.

2) bagging (with balance bootstrap sampling) tends to work really well when the problem is too hard to solve by a single classifier.

3) adaboost + SMOTE is known perform well on unbalanced data sets.

PS: I can share some useful references if required - just me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you called GentleBoost with uniform prior, all samples are treated the same. You should use empirical prior, which determines class probabilities from class frequencies. You should call fitensemble in the following manner:

```
ada = fitensemble(Xtrain,Ytrain,'GentleBoost',10,'Tree','LearnRate',0.1, 'prior', 'empirical');
```

or simply since the empirical prior is the default:

```
ada = fitensemble(Xtrain,Ytrain,'GentleBoost',10,'Tree','LearnRate',0.1);
```

You should also try to find an optimal number of learners, 10 is not necessarily optimal. 
An example for doing so can be found at [fitensemble(..) documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitensemble.html)